# Javascript - Motion Blur Image/Canvas

Tags: javascript

is there a way to do image processing with javascript on an image or a canvas?
I need to apply a motion blur with length/strength and an angle.
I also need to export the image then. Should also work on mobile devices.

Can I do that in real-time with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an SVG filter. Within an `<svg>` it looks like this:

```css
svg{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg>

  <filter id="verticalMotionBlur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0 5" />
  </filter>

  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="green" filter="url(#verticalMotionBlur)" />
  
</svg>
```

but you can also apply it to any other DOM element on your page, including an image:

```css
img {
  filter: url(#verticalMotionBlur)
}
```

```html
<svg>

  <filter id="verticalMotionBlur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0 5" />
  </filter>
  
</svg>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/>
```

Comment: You can downvote but unless you want to do the math in JS, that's the "native API" way of doing it.